# How can I remov permission denied for my app in the Facebook developers site?

Tags: facebook

I am working on some app using facebook login. We have requested to add user_gender, user_age_range permission before, we thought it would be needed for user analytics in the future. But we couldn't get permission from Facebook and it doesn't need for our app. So I want to remove this permission request from facebook developer console.

The reason why I removed this permission requested, when user enter the facebook login page, the page shows red alert to user about denied permission. It makes user frustrated about our app.

In the developer console, I can see the permissions denied and re-request button for those permissions but not remove those requests.

I think if I can remove those requests, the red alert will be gone.

Does anyone know about this issue?

---

EDITED:
I added the screenshot of the red alert.
It's in Korean. 
It says 'Grant an login permission. There are permissions denied from Facebook below. Grant for app review now or View Details.'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDUWQ.png)

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the alert?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added the screenshot. The alert in Korean. I couldn't find the way to show the alert in English. So I translated that in English above.

Comment: _“when user enter the facebook login page, the page shows red alert to user about denied permission. It makes user frustrated about our app.”_ - normal users, who do not have a role in your app, should not be seeing this warning in the first place - it gets shown to admins/developers of the app only.

Comment: _“I think if I can remove those requests, the red alert will be gone.”_ - no, it won’t. It will be gone, once you stop _asking_ for these permissions from within your own app’s coding.

Comment: @04FS As you said, it was just for admin. Nothing with normal users. Also we removed that code to request the permissions denied. And the message is gone. Thank you for your help. You saved me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is only visible to users with a role in the app (those set as admins, developers, or testers in the "Roles" section of the developers.facebook.com console).

As such, no real users will be frustrated by this. The unapproved permissions are just ignored.

It also has nothing to do with the permission request in the console. It's caused by requesting the unapproved scopes in **your** code. Find where you're requesting these scopes in the code and remove them.

Comment: Yes, as you and 04FS said, it wasn't visible to normal user. And removing the code also made the red alert gone. Thank you for your help.